# How to get the filtered dataframe for calculations while retaining the original one in pandas?

Tags: python, filter, pandas

and I have some confussion on how does pandas use filtered rows.
Say we have this market data dataframe 'df':

```
Time                    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
31.12.2003 23:00:00.000 82440   83150   82440   82880   47686.32
01.01.2004 23:00:00.000 82830   83100   82350   83100   37571.04
02.01.2004 23:00:00.000 83100   83100   83100   83100   0.00
```

Now we filter the rows to get a df only for the days that the markets are open (Volume>0)

```
df=df[df['Volume']>0]
```

Because of the way we filtered the dataframe, there are empty rows that still have indexes, and values, but they are not used in calculations, for instance, if we do:

```
df.mean()
```

The values of the filtered rows wont appear on the calculation.

The confusing part comes here:

How could we do the average of the last 2 values counting from row 3, using only the not filtered values?
Meaning, if we filtered out the row 2, it should get the mean of rows 3 and 1.

----------- EDIT --------------
Hey, thanks for the comment, trying to be more clear:

Say we have this example dataframe:

```
Index    Volume
0        1 
1        0
2        1
3        1
```

Then we filter it:

```
df=df[df['Volume']>0]
```

If we send the dataframe to numpy, in order to plot or work iterate through the dataframe, it will send also the rows that we dont want.

If we iterate over that data, it will also iterate (and consider) the indexes that we are ruling out.

So, how can we get a copy of the dataframe that excludes the ruled out rows, to avoid those two problems?

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you expect to get? Your wording is too ambiguous.

Comment: Im working on ipython to get a working example of what I mean, will post as soon as I find it. I realize this is not clear yet

Comment: Why do you think it will pass excluded rows? F.ex. in your last example `df[df['Volume']>0].values` will be an array of ones of shape (3, 1).

Comment: Because Im using such a dataframe to plot, and I get this: http://i.imgur.com/IMzT6TS.png
 So its getting excluded indexes from the dataframe even though they are excluded. (The spaces between candlesticks are excluded rows,but they still appear that way)

Comment: That's not rows but index. You might want simply do `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` to reindex your dataframe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45063/discussion-between-i-want-badges-and-alko)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into a pretty common problem with boolean indexing. When you're trying to filter a `DataFrame` with `DataFrame` of booleans, you need to specify how to handle cases where things are True for some columns/rows, but false for other columns/rows. Do you want items where things are True *everywhere*, or *anywhere*.

It's especially tricky in this case since your `DataFrame` is 1-d, so you'd expect things to work like a `Series`, where there's no ambiguity: with a `Series` a row is either True or False; it can't be True in some columns and False in others.

To resolve the ambiguity with `DataFrames`, use the `any()` or `all()` methods:

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
       Volume
Index        
0           1
1           0
2           1
3           1

[4 rows x 1 columns]

In [37]: df[(df > 0).all(1)]
Out[37]: 
       Volume
Index        
0           1
2           1
3           1

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

The `1` inside the `all()` just says across the `1` axis (the columns)

---

Here's a 2-d example that might help clear things up:

```
In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], "B": ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']})

In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
   A  B
0  a  e
1  b  f
2  c  g
3  d  h

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [41]: bf = pd.DataFrame({"A": [True, True, False, False], "B": [True, False, True, False]})

In [42]: bf
Out[42]: 
       A      B
0   True   True
1   True  False
2  False   True
3  False  False

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

First, the "wrong" way, with the ambiguity unresolved. It's unclear what to do with (1, 'B') since it's false in `bf`, but there is a `1` row and a `B` column, so a `NaN` is filled:

```
In [43]: df[bf]
Out[43]: 
     A    B
0    a    e
1    b  NaN
2  NaN    g
3  NaN  NaN

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

All matches only the first row, since that's the only one with both True:

```
In [44]: df[bf.all(1)]
Out[44]: 
   A  B
0  a  e

[1 rows x 2 columns]
```

`any` matches all but the last row, since that one has both `False`es

```
In [45]: df[bf.any(1)]
Out[45]: 
   A  B
0  a  e
1  b  f
2  c  g

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Wow It would have taken me a lot of time to figure that out by myself! Thanks for this valuable lesson!